# list contains NULL byte, CSV DictReader

Tags: python, csv

How can I remove NULL bytes using DictReader method? The following code produce error as 
Error: line contains NULL byte

```
with open('excelfile.csv', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as file:

reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=('BANK','IFSC', 'BRANCH', 'ADDRESS'))
for row in reader: 
    frame = {'bank': row['BANK'], 'ifsc': row['IFSC'], 'branch': row['BRANCH'], 'address': row['ADDRESS'] } 
    framelist.append(frame)
```

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show one line with *"NULL byte"*.

Comment: Your encoding is likely wrong, maybe `utf16`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your NULL bytes by an empty string. Like this:

```
 reader = csv.DictReader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in file)
```

Example:

```
with open('excelfile.csv', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as file:

   reader = csv.DictReader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in file)
   for row in reader: 
     frame = {'bank': row['BANK'], 'ifsc': row['IFSC'], 'branch': row['BRANCH'], 'address': row['ADDRESS'] } 
     framelist.append(frame)
```

Comment: If there are NULL bytes in the input, it is more likely the encoding is wrong.  `encoding=utf16` is more likely the solution.